# Error parsing DateTime

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to parse "time" strings for comparison purposes

```psh
$Test2 =[datetime]::Parse("24/09/2015 05:41:27",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US")) 
$Test2

$Test =[datetime]::Parse("23/09/2015 05:41:27",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US")) 
$Test


if($Test2 -gt $Test)
 write-host comparison works
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Parse" with "2" argument(s): "String was not recognized as
a valid DateTime."
At C:\Users\Desktop\ne.ps1:1 char:1
+ $Test =[datetime]::Parse("23/09/2015
05:41:27",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetC ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Comment: According to the setting the month and day are backwards. You could use `ParseExact` or possibly change your cultureinfo

Answer (score 4):

The `en-US` culture uses the month-day-year format, so you'll want to either:

1. Switch the culture you're using
2. Change the format of the input string

Here is a code sample:

```
### Change the date/time input string
[datetime]::Parse("09/23/2015 05:41:27")

### Use the Great Britain culture
[datetime]::Parse("23/09/2015 05:41:27", [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-GB'))
```

[image: DateTime]

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to say +1

Comment: Yep, you were right Matt. Thanks for the +1, just figured I would put it in an answer.

Comment: I didn't have time to test or write the answer. Was off to a meeting.

Comment: No worries -- if you want to answer it as well, go for it! :)

Comment: Found out that the dates are both in us and gb,  how can i parse both and place in some culture for comparison?

Comment: You could put a try..catch block around it. If it fails as `en-US`, then try `en-GB`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `/` is a *culture-sensitive date separator character*, another options would be:

set [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[datetime]::Parse("24/09/2015 05:41:27",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or utilize [`DateTime.ParseExact method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("23/09/2015 05:41:27","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",[Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```